# Script de download por método curl

Tags: php, libcurl

Estou tendo alguns problemas com o processo do `script` abaixo.

Literalmente ele está efetuando o download muito lento, e isso quando não ocorre o processo de download cair ou reiniciar do zero.

Existe alguma forma de consertar isso, de forma que o download seja efetuado normalmente, com um processo mais eficaz?

Os arquivos para download chegam no máximo a `350MB`.

**Atualização:** Alguém saberia me dizer qual e o problema eu já alterei no php.ini as configurações parametros de `memory_limit`, `post_max_size`, `upload_max_filesize` e `max_execution_time` e mesmo assim o processo de download continua lento.

```
<?php
$file = 'http://thumb.mais.uol.com.br/15540367.mp4';
download($file,314572800);


function download($file,$chunks){
    set_time_limit(0);
    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($file));
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Pragma: public');
    $size = get_size($file);
    header('Content-Length: '.$size);

    $i = 0;
    while($i<=$size){

    get_chunk($file,(($i==0)?$i:$i+1),((($i+$chunks)>$size)?$size:$i+$chunks));
        $i = ($i+$chunks);
    }

}

function chunk($ch, $str) {
    print($str);
    return strlen($str);
}

function get_chunk($file,$start,$end){
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $file);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RANGE, $start.'-'.$end);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, 'chunk');
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
}

function get_size($url){
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true);
    curl_exec($ch);
    $size = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_CONTENT_LENGTH_DOWNLOAD);
    return intval($size);
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    //Tempo de execução ilimitado, visto que você
    //baixará arquivos grandes
    set_time_limit(0);     
    /*Ponteiro do Curl*/
    $ch = curl_init();

    /*Ponteiro do arquivo que será salvo*/
    $fp = fopen($destino, "w");

    /*Configuração*/
    $options = [
                 CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true, //preciso da resposta armazenada
                 CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 120,         // limite de 120 segundos
                 CURLOPT_URL => $url,            //recurso a ser procurado
                 CURLOPT_FILE => $fp,            //ponteiro do arquivo
                 CURLOPT_HEADER => false,        //Para não corromper o arquivo
               ];

    /*Aplica a configuração*/
    curl_setopt_array($ch, $options);

    /*Baixa o arquivo*/
    curl_exec($ch);

    /*Fecha o ponteiro do arquivo*/
    fclose($fp);

    /*Fecha o Curl*/
    curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: @Striffer, depois do arquivo baixado para teu servidor, basta que envies o arquivo para teu cliente, via download.